# Capitalized words with UTF-8 in Hunspell

Tags: utf-8, sublimetext2, spell-checking, hunspell

I'm trying to use [Hunspell](http://hunspell.sourceforge.net/) for spellchecking in Polish.

I did convert encoding of a dictionary from http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Dictionaries to UTF-8. However, **capitalized words** (i.e. with first letter in uppercase) **with a non-latin character are considered misspelled** (but the spellchecker suggests the same word). Other words are fine.

Such issue was raised on their bug-tracking a few years ago [False negatives with leading capital letter and UTF-8 - ID: 1432866](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1432866&group_id=143754&atid=756395). However, either this solution does not work, or I miss something.

Is there a solution for this problem?

In my `pl_PL.aff` file the leading lines are:

```
SET UTF-8
TRY aioeznrwcysptkmdłuljągbhęśćóżfńźvqxAIOEZNRWCYSPTKMDŁULJĄGBHĘŚĆÓŻFŃŹVQX
```

(Just in case, I'm using it in Sublime Text 2, but I doubt whether it makes a difference.)

Answer (score 2):

I've found Sublime specific dictionaries on github: https://github.com/SublimeText/Dictionaries. They somehow have fixed this error.

Comment: Thx, I didn't know that. However, the Polish dictionary there works much worse.